# Individual dask array boundaries with ghosting

Tags: dask

I'm playing with **Dask** trying to set up a few simple PDE solves using finite differences and I'm wondering if there's a way to specify boundary conditions per-boundary.

Docs [here](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/ghost.html)

The current `ghost.ghost` function allows specifying a few different B.C.s but they're always the same for both y-boundaries and both x-boundaries.

Docs mention that I can pad out a boundary arbitrarily, which I'm happy to do, but is there then a way to tell `ghost.ghost` to *not* add any boundaries on the outside of the chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `ghost_internal`

It appears that at the moment there *isn't* a way to do this from the user-facing `ghost` or `map_overlap` functions.  However, you can use the `dask.array.ghost.ghost_internal` function to accomplish internal ghosting without specifying external boundaries (this is the main function used by `ghost`).

```
In [1]: import dask.array as da

In [2]: x = da.arange(10, chunks=5)

In [3]: x.chunks
Out[3]: ((5, 5),)

In [4]: y = da.ghost.ghost_internal(x, {0: 2})

In [5]: y.chunks
Out[5]: ((7, 7),)

In [6]: y.compute()
Out[6]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

You may want to do this, then call `map_blocks` on the larger blocks and then call `dask.array.ghost.trim_internal` to trim away the excess overlap with the same axis depth.

But more generally this should be accessible from the more convenient `ghost` and `map_overlap` functions.  Can I ask you to [raise an issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/dask/issues/new)?

#### Finite Differences

More generally to the application of finite differences.  Dask.arrays are somewhat limited here because they refuse to mutate existing data.  This results in many copies which run a bit slower than a simple finite differencing scheme.  The cost of copying would be less painful for more costly computations.  Here is a quick [notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/mrocklin/dc7fd426a6e405fef275) that demonstrates this slowdown.  Since creating that notebook the copying overhead has been reduced by a factor of two, but is still significant.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll raise an issue now.  And thanks for the notebook -- I suspected the copy cost would overwhelm the threading benefit but it's good to have confirmation.